# QT how to pass Enum to EnumHelper correctly

Tags: qt, enums

I have found a helper class for enums (EnumHelper) to convert enums to strings and strings to enums.

I want to use this class in another class (MyEnums) in which I define different enums and want to provide a ToString() and FromString() method for each enum type.

If I try to convert an enum from a third class (Test) I get an error message that I don't understand.

EnumHelper.h

```
#pragma once
#include <QMetaEnum>

template <typename E>

class EnumHelper
{
public:

    EnumHelper();
    QString toString(E value);
};
```

EnumHelper.cpp

```
#include "EnumHelper.h"

template<typename E>
EnumHelper<E>::EnumHelper()
{
}

template<typename E>
QString EnumHelper<E>::toString(E value)
{
    const int retval = static_cast<int>(value);
    return QString::fromUtf8(QMetaEnum::fromType<E>().valueToKey(retval));
}
```

MyEnums.h

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
#include "EnumHelper.h"

class ColorNameEnums
{
    Q_GADGET
public:
    enum Value {
        White,
        Grey,
        LightGrey,
        DarkerGrey,
        DarkGrey,
        Mint, 
        DarkMint,
        Red,
        DarkRed,
        Black,
        Blue
    };
    Q_ENUM(Value)

private:
    explicit ColorNameEnums();
};

class MyEnums : QObject
{
public:
    explicit MyEnums(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    QString colorNameToString(ColorNameEnums value);
    ColorNameEnums colorNameFromString(QString value);

private:
    EnumHelper<ColorNameEnums> m_colorName;

};
```

MyEnums.cpp

```
#include "MyEnums.h"

MyEnums::MyEnums(QObject* parent)
{
}

QString MyEnums::colorNameToString(ColorNameEnums value) { return m_colorName.toString(value); }

ColorNameEnums MyEnums::colorNameFromString(QString value) { return m_colorName.fromString(value); }
```

Test.h

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
#include "MyEnums.h"

class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Test(QObject* parent = nullptr);

private:
    MyEnums* m_enums = new MyEnums();
};
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

Test::Test(QObject* parent)
{
}

void Test::test()
{

    auto xx = m_enums->colorNameToString(ColorNameEnums::White);
}
```

Error is:

```
For a conversion of ""ColorNameEnums::Value"" to""ColorNameEnums"" no suitable constructor is available.
```

Comment: Like the error says, `ColorNameEnums::Value` is your actual enum, but you try converting to `ColorNameEnums`, which is a class type and can't be implicitly converted to the `Value` enum type. Try `EnumHelper<ColorNameEnums::Value> m_colorName`

Comment: Sorry for late response - this is how it works